# How to link commands between user control and main in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a user control which have one `TextBox` and one `Button` called View. The `TextBox` takes index values.

On my `Main` view, I have one list view which will display all lines in a file.
An `ObservableCollection` is Bind to this.

What I need is, when **index** value is entered in the `TextBox` and View `Button` is clicked(in the user control), the `SelecedIndex` of the `ListView`(in the Main) should be changed to the **index** value.

How can I achieve this using MVVM?

Also, **Please provide the proper approach to do this if I am doing it wrong.**

Here is my UserControl Code:

**XAML**

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <VM:IndexView_VM ></VM:IndexView_VM>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid Background="White">
    <TextBlock Margin="10,12,168,9" Text="Index : "/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Index}" x:Name="TB_Index" Margin="53,11,90,8" />
    <Button Command="{Binding View_CMD}" x:Name="BT_View" Content="View" Margin="136,11,10,8" />
</Grid>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class IndexView_VM : ViewModelBase
{
    public IndexView_VM()
    {
        View_CMD = new RelayCommand(_View_CMD);
    }

    int _Index;
    public int Index
    {
        get { return _Index; }
        set
        {
            _Index = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand View_CMD { get; set; }
    internal void _View_CMD(object Parameter)
    {
        // What to write here?
    }
}
```

Here is the Main View:

**XAML**

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
        <VM:MainView_VM></VM:MainView_VM>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid Background="White">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="111*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel>
            <local:IndexView/>
            <local:IndexView/>
            <local:IndexView/>
            <local:IndexView/>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FileData}" x:Name="listView" Grid.Column="1" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Data" Width="100"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

**View Model**

```
public class MainView_VM : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainView_VM()
    {
        ReadFile();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> FileData { get; set; }

    void ReadFile()
    {
        //I will read file here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very basic example of what you want to do:

**Window XAML**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:StringToIntConverter x:Key="StringToIntConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock>Select Index</TextBlock>
    <TextBox x:Name="theTextBox" Text="{Binding SelectedIndex,ElementName=theList,Converter={StaticResource StringToIntConverter},Mode=OneWayToSource,UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Select Now</Button>
    <ListBox x:Name="theList">
        <ListBoxItem>First</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Second</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Third</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

**Window CodeBehind**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    theTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty)?.UpdateSource();
}
```

**Explanation**

You were asking to set the index on a list from a textbox by clicking a button. We bind the TextBox to the selected index with a couple of settings:

- Source: SelectedIndex
- ElementName: The List/Target UI Element
- Converter: Required to get from String to Int (i wrote on myself)
- Mode: OneWayToSource, we force the textbox to only send values to the list and not the other way round
- UpdateSourceTrigger: We do not want the binding to auto-update, we want to do this ourselves

To update the binding we use the Click Event of the button.

**But what about the view model?**
The operation is a View-Only operation, the ViewModel doesn't need to know anything about it, so we should leave it out of the operation. That's why I'm not using a CommandBinding.

**Whoops, forgot about the `UserControl`**
If you want to put this in a user control then i suggest that you don't create a ViewModel at all. Also in the user control you don't need DataBinding, only on the outside. Keep it simple:

**UserControl XAML**

```
<TextBlock>Select Index</TextBlock>
<TextBox x:Name="theTextBox" />
<Button Click="Button_Click">Select Now</Button>
```

**UserControl CodeBehind**

```
public int Index
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(IndexProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IndexProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty IndexProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Index", typeof(int), typeof(ListViewIndexSelectorControl), new PropertyMetadata(0));
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(int.TryParse(theTextBox.Text, out int result))
    {
        Index = result;
    }
}
```

**MainWindow Usage XAML**

```
<local:ListViewIndexSelectorControl Index="{Binding SelectedIndex,ElementName=theList,Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
<ListBox x:Name="theList">
    <ListBoxItem>First</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Second</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Third</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

If you later on need a ViewModel, you can also use the View as the ViewModel for simple controls, just set `DataContext = this;` in the View's constructor or use a Name on the XAML element and bind the DataContext by ElementName.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `MvvmLight`, you could for example use the `Messenger` class to send a message from the child view model to the parent:

**IndexView_VM:**

```
internal void _View_CMD(object Parameter)
{
    GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.Messenger.Default.Send(_Index);
}
```

**MainView_VM:**

```
public class MainView_VM : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainView_VM()
    {
        ReadFile();
        GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.Messenger.Default.Register<int>(this, index => Index = index);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> FileData { get; set; }

    int _Index;
    public int Index
    {
        get { return _Index; }
        set
        {
            _Index = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    void ReadFile()
    {
        //I will read file here.
    }
}
```

**MainView:**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FileData}" x:Name="listView" Grid.Column="1"
          SelectedIndex="{Binding Index}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Data" Width="100"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Please refer to Laurent Bugnion's MSDN Magazine article for more information about the `Messenger`.

**MVVM - Messenger and View Services in MVVM:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj694937.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand this right. You want to set the selected item of your `ListBox` using the index value you type in that `TextBox`, is this right?

If this is is right then I have the following considerations:

1. In this scenario a `UserControl` is probably overkill. *Especially* if you are going to never re-use it somewhere else in your UI.
2. Given the first consideration, all you have to do is move that `TextBox` to your main view, give it a name and bind the `.Text` Property to your `ListView`'s `SelectedIndex` Property.

Example:

```
<ListView SelectedIndex="{Binding ElementName=txtIndex, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource StringToIntConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

That converter (which you would need to implement) is needed because converting a `string` to an `int` won't probably happen automatically. `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` will update the target Property as soon as you type, removing the need for a button.

At that point you should be done.

If you absolutely need that `UserControl`, you could add a `DependencyProperty` exposing the `TextBox`'s value. Then you could bind to that Property as in the example above.

Comment: To use the button you can set the `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit` and then use the UpdateSource method in the code behind.

Comment: I think turning around the Binding (bind on the textbox) would be more appropriate in this case. (the textbox pushes values to the view). Set the Mode to OneWayToSource and again, use Explicit & UpdateSource´